# Excel IF(Countif =7-cell)

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

im trying to to fin how many closed toll gates in a project is on time in full based on how many closed there are.

So cell a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1 contains string ON TIME if a tollgates i on time. ( blank if its not closed and delay if not on time)

I then have formula in H1 `=COUNTBLANK(project_master_data[@[Work Order]:[Total Actual]])` to count blanks (not closed tollgates)

An then I have in I1 `=IF(COUNTIF(project_master_data[@[Pre-study scheduled start]:[Implement Actual]];"on time")=7;"Yes";"No")` to count how many "on time" there are (on full should be 7) but i want it to be dynamic to the number of closed tollgates.

So i tried `=IF(COUNTIF(project_master_data[@[Pre-study scheduled start]:[Implement Actual]];"on time")=7-h1;"Yes";"No")` but i doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *want it to be dynamic to the number of closed tollgates.* What does that mean?

Comment: I mean if there are 7 tollgates in total when the project is closed and all of them are on time the project in full are on time therefore countif=7. but if the project are in progress and there are 2 tollgates not closed yet. I want it to subtract that from =7. since the project in full still can on time based on which stage it is in.

Comment: I'm still not understanding; but it sounds as if it is just a matter of using the correct comparisons in your `COUNTIF` function.  If each column represents a tollgate, then the number of tollgates can be obtained from the `COLUMNS` function.

Comment: A1:G1 Calculate actual finish time for tollgate. ("","ON TIME","DELAY")
H1 Counts how many blanks there are in A1:G1
I1 Counts how many on time there are in A1:G1 (if a project i complete this should be 7) and returns "YES","NO"
When a project is NOT completed and there are 3 not closed tollgates H1 Should count it to 3. and i want that to impact the I1 formula. instead of =7 i want it to be =7-H1

Comment: Edit your question to clarify it. Include an example of your data, actual output and desired output. It might help me to help you if you first read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then either edit your original question to improve it, or ask a new one if the original has been closed.